# free() not working correctly with struct

Tags: c, struct, free

After calling free() the memory allocated for my struct should be free'd. So why is my code still printing `l->val` ? why does it fail when trying to print `l->key` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node {
     char *key;
     char *val;
} Node;

int main(void) {
    Node *l=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    l->key="foo";
    l->val="bar";
    free(l);
    printf("%s\n", l->val);
    //printf("%s\n", l->key); /* this gives an error */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well what do you expect `l->val` to do when you have already freed `l`? It's been **destroyed.** There's no such thing as `l`, nor `l->val` at the point you are trying to use it.

Comment: C don't care what address you are referencing. get out of the languages with exceptions.

Comment: My question is why the code keeps printing `l->val` even after it's destroyed

Comment: Why does `printf("%s\n", l->val);` still work? Pure luck, the memory location is still intact. Why does `printf("%s\n", l->key);` fail? Bad luck, the memory location has already been overwritten. C is like that in such situations.

Comment: It works because you were lucky, but it's still UB.

Comment: Google about *undefined behavior*; it is scary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always a good habit to set the pointer to NULL after freeing it.
Since the memory you are accessing is still intact you are seeing right values for l->val.

```
Node *l=malloc(sizeof(Node));
l->key="foo";
l->val="bar";
free(l);
l = NULL;
```

Answer (score -2):

the execution of `free(l);` frees the memory pointed by `l` ie it could be used again with another `malloc()` or another memory use. Since then, before the memory is allocated and changed, it generally keeps the same content. so reading `l` gives the last content of `l` before it's freed.

Comment: You don't *have* to allocate memory for `l->var` and `l->key`. You can have them pointing to static objects, for example, like he did in his code.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves :  i thought initializing whith a string litteralk must be done with the declaration. Otherwise, it is not legal...

Comment: @HichamfromCppDependTeam Initializing a character array from a string literal must be done at declaration. In this special case, the code `char wurzle[] = "Wimbledon"` is defined as being equivalent to `char wurzle[] = {'W', 'i', 'm', 'b', 'l', 'e', 'd', 'o', 'n', '\0'}`. However, you can always assign a string literal to a pointer-to-char.